# Android "wrap_content" and "minHeight" issue

Tags: android, button, size, absolutelayout

I am having some difficulties setting up three simple buttons, created and exported in .png format. Their size is about 160x60px. In the activity_main.xml I have set for the height and width: "wrap_content" and created for each resolution (ldpi, mdpi...) the corresponding button sizes. As I view the Graphic Layout or test the app my buttons are stretched in height.

I figured out that in the "Property Inspector" the default minHeight and minWidth are set automatically to 48x64 dp, and I can't delete these values...I even tried to enter again "wrap_content" but it gives me an error. For now I have modified the "minHeight" to 40dp and my buttons are ok, but I am worried about screen compatibly and about having issues in the future on other different devices.

How to solve this properly?
Thanks!

[image: Stretched Buttons]

[image: Default minHeiht issue]